# Configuring SharePoint 2007 with Apache Reverse Proxy -- issues with relative URLs

Tags: 2007

This question was posted at ServerFault before I realized there was a community dedicated to SharePoint here.

Essentially, we've been tasked with placing our entire SharePoint 2007 app behind an Apache reverse proxy, which maps it to a URL with a subdirectory. So, http://www-s.site.com/app goes to internalapp.site.com/ This, unfortunately, is an unchanging requirement.

The issue occurs because Apache rewrites the headers just fine, but not the links. So to re-map all relative URLs in SharePoint (think links, document locations, CSS files, javascript, etc.) is proving close to impossible.

I was wondering: has anyone had experience trying to remap URLs from SharePoint for a reason such as this?

A parallel question: Does anyone know of a way to convert all SharePoint relative URLs to absolutes as they're generated? If we could get the relative URLs to be absolute, our Regex replaces on Apache would at least be much cleaner.

I'm open to any method of achieving this and am happy to provide more details. I know the question is a little muddled (apologies); the team is new to apache and it's been a kick in the brain to try to figure this out a few days before launch.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Comment: Voting to close as I think this is such an obscure scenario and I don't think anybody has any useful suggestions. Sorry.

Comment: Fine and understood. Because of the scenario we ended up moving away from the platform and porting to a normal .NET app.